# How to create an ASP.NET route that redirects to a path that uses part of the route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I want to create a route that redirects all requests matching certain pattern to a location built using parts of the pattern. I want to grab some segment in the URL and treat the rest like a path to an aspx page in Web Forms application. For example

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("SomeRouteName", "{something}/{*path}", "~/pages/{*path}/Default.aspx");
```

Where *path could be something contain "\". The query string should be preserved as a query string.

Is it possible to create souch a route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at several ways to do this I ended up creating my own routing handler that is something like this:

```
public class SomethingRoutingHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string something = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["something"];
        string path = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["path"];

        string virtualPath = "~/" + path + "Default.aspx";

        return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as Page;
    }
}
```

I then use the RouteData in the pages to access something. I found these articles helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Default-Route-in-ASPNET-4-URL-Routing.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do it that way.

The more standard way would be to set the target as "~/pages/default.aspx" and then have that page check for the `{path}` argument and display the corresponding data.

If you really want it in another path, then don't use a `{}` placeholder. Simply hard code that section of the path (both the source and target).

Comment: The second solution would require hardcoding paths for many existing pages and I was hoping to avoid the first solution. Also there seems to be a way to pass in a route handler class that allows handling the routing with code but I was hoping for more clean solution.

Comment: @Stilgar: AFAIC, `MapPageRoute()` is primarily designed for cases where path elements represent information that is used to retrieve the target content, usually from a database. To the best of my knowledge, it simply wasn't designed to do what you want. If you have a lot of paths, then handling the route with code may be your best solution.